# Embed Youtube video in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video, youtube, embed

I have a textbox where users can enter the link to a YouTube video. I'd like to have an `<object>` on my page which gets populated with the YouTube video. I tried accessing an `<object>` from the codebehind (with `runat=server`) set to true, but I couldn't.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out the full HTML value to a `LiteralControl`. That way you don't have to worry about having asp.net render that out for you, you can control it closely